# CodeIgniter URL routing - SEO friendly URL

Tags: codeigniter, routes, seo

I've created a new route for my site:

$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";

$route['(:any)'] = "welcome/index/$1";

$route['404_override'] = '';

And this works fine in my site when URL is like this:

http://mydomain.com/first-article

http://mydomain.com/second-article

*my controller is just welcome.php

but

i also have a controller for the admin and the URL for the admin is:

http://mydomain.com/admin

What will I add to the routes file to ignore the /admin and other controllers inside the admin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the `welcome/index/$1` route with:

```
$route['^(?!admin).*'] = "welcome/index/$1";
```

This basically says, that if a URI that does **not** start with "admin" should route to the welcome/index method and pass the contents to the index method. Otherwise, handle normal routing with admin being the controller.

Comment: thanks for the reply and it works!..but what if i want to add one more rule let say: if a URI does not start with "admin" and "users" it should route to the welcome/index method..how would i do this?

Comment: Just add it in the routes separated with the pipe character:  `$route['^(?!admin|users).*'] = "welcome/index/$1";`  --  you can add as many as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Open **application/config/router.php** and change the

```
$route['404_override'] = '';
```

to

```
$route['404_override'] = 'router/index';
```

You can use all controllers as the normal way.

When you try to use a controller that is not exists, you should route it to a 404 controller.

Create a controller named **Router.php** as a controller structured for CodeIgniter.

In the **index** method inside **Router.php**, query for related sef url and do required operations. All requests that routes to an undefined controller will be handled by **router/index** method. Others will be redirected to related controller as usual.

You might want to use header codes to point that related page is not 404.